# In Install4j8 - How to redirect to some screen when user clicks on Cancel button

Tags: install4j

In installer(multiplatform) we have the use case like Install upgrade and rollback. 
While performing the upgrade installation if user clicks to cancel button,
We would like to go to the rollback screen, where user can perform rollback actions.

I have tried the run script with event listener in startup actions like below , but did not work:

```
   context.addInstallerEventListener(new InstallerEventListener() {
   public void installerEvent(InstallerEvent installerEvent) {
        if (installerEvent.getType() == EventType.CANCELED) {
            context.gotoScreen(context.getScreenById("5866"));
        }
    }
});
return true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit your styles and replace the cancel button with your own button.

Assuming you use the standard styles, go to Installer->Style, edit "Standard footer" and look for the "Cancel button" style component. You can add a "Button" form component with a script that switches to a particular screen.

Comment: No, this is just for the GUI,